# Getting name of Page being requested/was requested

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, webmatrix

I know this is easy, but I've forgotten how and since I can't remember what it's called; it's been difficult trying to search for a solution.

How can we request the page name in C#?

E.g.:

```
String pageName = String.Empty;
if(IsPost)
{
   pageName = Request.PageName; // example only
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the answer cleaner

```
public string GetPageName() 
{ 
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; 
    System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(path); 
    return info.Name; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashley! The code above gives the full filepath, I expanded it a little so it gives just the Filename without extension: `string pageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the .aspx file name:

```
pageName = Page.Request.Url.Segments[Page.Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1];
```

There are some good samples of using the URI class at:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/uri

Answer (score 0):

```
string pageName = Request.UrlReferrer != null ? System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath) : Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1];
```

This can be used with `Url` rewrite too.

Comment: I believe this will work all the time without URLReferer stuff:

pageName = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("_(.*?)_aspx").Match(this.Page.ToString()).Groups[1].Value;